# Using LDoc to document table of functions

Tags: lua

ldoc will happily document a function like

```
--- Foo function
-- does a foo
function foo(param1, param2)
end
```

However, what I'd like to do is make it document a table of function pointers.

e.g.

```
--- bar.lua ---
bar = {
   foo = function(a, b, c)
   end
}

return bar

--- foo.lua ---
local bar = require "bar"

fooapi {
    foo = bar.foo
}
```

I would like to document this in terms of fooapi as this is an exported API over a socket and I'd like to hide where it's implemented specifically. It needs to come out in relation to `fooapi` and I don't want to see any mention of bar.lua or bar.foo in the output.

So if I put comments after the `foo = bar.foo` line and before `fooapi` table, then the resulting documentation lists it as just an ordinary table field rather than actually a function.

Is there a way to override this behaviour so that ldoc will produce output like `function fooapi.foo with parameters a,b,c` ?

I'm expecting to tell it about parameters that are not shown and to somehow override it's type to be a function with it's name overriden to include the nesting in the table rather than just an ordinary table field?  note the nesting of the functions can go several levels deep in the exposed API.

I'm open to restructuring the code if needed.  Or even switching to a more different or more flexible tool.  In fact, I don't mind if it doesn't pull out any info from the lua code but merely produces code completely from special comments in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit tags, and you're good to go!

```
--- Function that Foos.
-- Does the foo things of fooapi.
-- @function fooapi.foo
-- 
-- @tparam boolean a AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.
-- @tparam number b bBbBbB.
-- @tparam string c Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet.
```

Comment: Thanks, I later discovered this after much poking around and trial and error.  It didn't format too well originally.